# generic template function for addition

Tags: c++, templates

I am new learner of C++. I wants to write generic code that will work for all data types. I believe I have to write template function named add() in my program and it should take two argument of template that will add these passed parameters and return the result of addition. i.e.

```
template <class T> 
T add (T value1, T value2){
     T sum = value1+value2;
    return sum;
}
```

And within main() function, I want to call the template function add() for int, float and Complex types.

```
int v1 = 5, v2 = 6 ; 
    cout << "Addtion of int values = " << add(v1, v2);
float x = 2.3, y = 3.5 ;
    cout << "Addtion of float values = " << add(x, y);
Complex c1(2, 3), c2(2, 3), t ;
    cout << "Addtion of complex values = " << add(c1, c2);
```

but in add function, what kind of code i need to write to add these types of arguments ?

Comment: Have you tried this code?

Comment: So, you're writing [std::plus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig i am using dev-c++ tool, so i dont need to use std::

Comment: it is depends on whether the type implemented the opeartor `+`.

Comment: A warning here: You might *not* want to write functions that take **any** data type. For example, if you use my library in your code, I definitely don't want you to add functions that accidentally modifiy my types in unexpected ways. You're adding a shotgun to the code - watch your feet!

Answer (score 0):

> in add function, do I need to write specialized code for each type

No, you don't, if the type can be used with `operator+`. That is what template function do for you.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XKON6734)

Comment: but, @songyuanyao  in add function, what kind of code i need to write to add these types of arguments ?

Comment: @roshan You've done it, just `T sum = value1+value2;`. What are you worried about?

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand the key points of templates.I am listing them point wise.

1. the word 'template' in dictionary means a predefined pattern to create similar objects.
2. funtion templates in c++ are similar,they are used to create same function but with different arguments or parameters
3. we define templates functions using placeholder type parameters,in your case the placeholder type is  class T type parameters
4. you must have noticed that you cant call a template function directly,because the compiler does not know the placeholder types directly in your defined template function,instead it replaces those placeholder types with your definition of the parameters ,provided in your function call.In this manner it can create several flavours of the same function from your template.
5. now i am comming to your code,you need to write only one generic code,because when you call the function with different data types,the template creates instances of each type automatically.If you have to write different versions for each datatype then you could have overloaded the method instead of using templates.The advantage of templates is that it acts as a generic type function and its instances for different data types are created automatically when the compiler encounters the templated function call in your code.
   I would also like to add something,in your code you have called the templated function for complex types.Well templates work with your defined types also,but here you must remember one thing that when you are using templates with user defined types ,in your case the complex class,you must also overload the neccessary operators that are used in your templated function i.e you must overload the + operator otherwise the statement Complex c1(2, 3), c2(2, 3), t ;
   cout << "Addtion of complex values = " << add(c1, c2); will throw an error.

please share your feedback,i am awating for your reply.